# In Xamarin how i can send data off a list to the listView?

Tags: android, xamarin

I there.
I trying to create a small aplication and i have one big problem, how i cant send data from my list to listview ? i see many documents explain but i can understand how i can do. Sorry my english too.

```
    private List<noticias> Noticias = new List<noticias>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("402 Clube Portugal", "teste");

        string connectionString = @"server=xxxxx;port=xxxxx;database=xxxx;user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM noticias", conn);
                MySqlDataReader dados = comando.ExecuteReader();

                while (dados.Read())
                {
                    noticias f = new noticias();
                    f.numero = (int)dados["numero"];
                    f.titulo = (string)dados["titulo"];
                    f.descricao = (string)dados["descricao"];
                    // f.imagem = (byte)dados["imagem"];
                    Noticias.Add(f);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(MySqlException )
        {         
        }
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Comment: the docs address this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating

Comment: Can you please share the code of your ListView. I don’t see it anywhere. Also what tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: your layout doesn't contain a ListView element